# How can I make a connection object without an open connection in R?

Tags: r

I cannot seem to create a closed connection object.  I want to have a connection object sitting around, so I can give it a connection if `isOpen(myCon)` returns `FALSE`.  I would expect `myCon<-file()` to give me a closed connection, but `isOpen(myCon)` returns `TRUE`.  I see from the help file that `file()` actually returns a connection to an "anonymous file", which is apparently just a memory location that acts like a file. ...not what I want.  If I create the anonymous file and execute `close(myCon)`, then `isOpen(myCon)` gives an invalid connection error rather than returning `FALSE`.  I don't want to be trapping errors just to get my false value.  How can I create a valid connection that's not open?  There must be a way `isOpen(myCon)` can return `FALSE`, otherwise it's a somewhat pointless function.  My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `f = file(tempfile()); isOpen(f); open(f, "a"); isOpen(f); close(f); isOpen(f)` (except for the last one, which throws the invalid connection error).

Comment: It's not really meant for telling if the connection is just open, the important part is the `rw=` parameter. This allows you to test if the connection is open for read or writing or both. So maybe it's just not a well named function.

Comment: Martin Morgan:  Actually, `file("dumdum")` works as long as the file, dumdum, doesn't exist. I expected that to throw a warning or error, so I didn't try it. Anyway, I'm glad I didn't, because I didn't know about tempfile(). I like that better, because it guarantees the file doesn't exist. If you post `file(tempfile())` as an answer, I'll select it. I won't be using `open(f,"a")`. When I am ready to use the object, there will be a specific file to open. I just want the object sitting in the global environemt, so I can test it for an existing connection. The dummy filename will get discarded.

Comment: Update:  This is simpler than I imagined. `file("anything")` works whether the file, anything, exists or not.  The key is that the open parameter is left empty and the description parameter is not empty.  I had assumed that R would try to open the connection as read-only.  I guess I've been working too much in Perl lately, and I should have read the help page more carefully.  I'll post the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file() works as long as the first parameter (description) is a non-empty string.  Example:

```
> myCon <- file("dumdum")
> isOpen(myCon)
[1] FALSE
```

The key is that the second parameter (open) is left empty (the default).  It does not matter whether the string used for description is an existing file or not.  However, this does not mean that the connection can't be used.  R opens the connection as needed.  For example:

```
> myCon <- file("important log file.txt")
> isOpen(myCon)
[1] FALSE
> cat("Thinking this will fail, because the connection is closed.  ...wrong!", file=myCon)
> isOpen(myCon)
[1] FALSE
```

The file has just been overwritten with that one line.

The safe way to make a stand-by connection is to generate the description with tempfile().  That returns a string which is guaranteed "not to be currently in use" (...according to the help page.  I interpret that to mean that the string is not the name of an existing file.)

```
> myCon <- file( tempfile() )
> isOpen(myCon)
[1] FALSE
> cat("Didn't mean to do this, but all it will do is create a new file.", file=myCon)
> isOpen(myCon)
[1] FALSE
```

In this case, that line was written to a file, but it did not overwrite anything.

Many thanks to Martin Morgan for pointing me in the right direction.  I welcome additional comments.